# Big Oh Notation - Discrete Math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

I am learning big oh notation and i can say that i have understood the basics of this method. But there are some questions that i do not know how to solve.

Some questions are:

```
nlg(n) = [ ] nlg(lg(n^3))

5^n = [ ] (3^n + 2^n)

lg(n^2) = [ ] lg(n^3)
```

The [ ] is the blank that needs to be filled with either O, omega or theta.
I have the answers to the questions above. But i do not understand how to solve them. 
The way i solved this before was by plugging in values for n and using the calculator to see if f(n) is big or g(n) is big and vice-versa.
Since my exam is going to be no calculators, can anyone help me understand how to solve these questions without calculators.

P.S, there is no need to solve all of them. I just want to know the technique for finding the answers.

Thank you!!

Comment: A possibility: first, do obvious simplifications with the logarithms ($\log n^k = k\log n$, etc.) Then, you can divide the left hand side by the other (RHS) and look at the limit when $n\to\infty$. Is it 0, $\infty$, a constant $c>0$?

Comment: For the second question, you need to figure out whether $(3+2)^n \ge 3^n + 2^n$ or $(3+2)^n \le 3^n + 2^n$. For the third, first simplify both sides and then figure out the same thing.